# sed back reference

Tags: sed

I have the following lines, stored in the text file *tel2*:

```
Hernandez Darin, Alberto|plaza mayor|13190|Corral de Calatrava|926/448/829
Gomez Badenas, Josefina|calle Sagasta|13190|Corral de Calatrava|926.443.602
```

My intention is to put the phone number as the start of each line, so I did:

```
sed 's/\(.*13...|[^|]*\)\(.*\)$/\2\1/' tel2.txt
```

I got only the first group as the output, ignoring the second captured group. But if I put a \n between \2 and \1, it outputs the second group first, and the first in a new line, so it is not the regex.
   Is the first group overwriting the second?, am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your file have DOS-style CRLF line endings by any chance? (Check with `file tel2.txt` or using `cat -et`)

Comment: Yes, it has, at the end of each line a `^M$`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments, the issue is that your file has DOS-style CRLF line endings, and your second capture group is capturing the CR and moving it to the middle of the output pattern, as you can see using `cat -et` to make the line endings explicit:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*13...|[^|]*\)\(.*\)$/\2\1/' tel2.txt | cat -et
|926/448/829^MHernandez Darin, Alberto|plaza mayor|13190|Corral de Calatrava$
|926.443.602^MGomez Badenas, Josefina|calle Sagasta|13190|Corral de Calatrava$
```

A possible solution would be to exclude the CR from the second group:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*13...|[^|]*\)\(.*\)\r$/\2\1\r/' tel2.txt | cat -et
|926/448/829Hernandez Darin, Alberto|plaza mayor|13190|Corral de Calatrava^M$
|926.443.602Gomez Badenas, Josefina|calle Sagasta|13190|Corral de Calatrava^M$
```

(if you don't want DOS-style endings in the result, omit the `\r` in the replacement).

---

I suspect you don't really want the delimiter at the front - a simpler expression that handles the delimiters more sensibly would be

```
sed 's/\(.*\)|\([^|]*\)\r/\2|\1\r/'
```

ex.:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\)|\([^|]*\)\r/\2|\1\r/' tel2.txt | cat -et
926/448/829|Hernandez Darin, Alberto|plaza mayor|13190|Corral de Calatrava^M$
926.443.602|Gomez Badenas, Josefina|calle Sagasta|13190|Corral de Calatrava^M$
```